# Python: TypeError: item 1 in _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, typeerror

I just updated my PC and when I try to run the same program I have started receiving this issue. Earlier it was running perfectly fine. I am using  anaconda with python 3.7.6. I tried to look up the details but I am not able to sought it out.
When I try to run my program, I receive:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Namrata/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/Namrata/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 121, in WINFUNCTYPE
    return _win_functype_cache[(restype, argtypes, flags)]

KeyError: (<class 'ctypes.HRESULT'>, (<class 'comtypes.automation.tagVARIANT'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.VARIANT_BOOL'>, <class 'ctypes.wintypes.VARIANT_BOOL'>), 0)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 103, in <module>
    app = MyApp()

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\Desktop\untitled0.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.gd = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(p, 'DATARAYOCX.GetDataCtrl.1')

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wx\lib\activex.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._ax = cc.GetBestInterface(unknown)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 110, in GetBestInterface
    mod = GetModule(tlib)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 110, in GetModule
    mod = _CreateWrapper(tlib, pathname)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 184, in _CreateWrapper
    mod = _my_import(fullname)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_generate.py", line 24, in _my_import
    return __import__(fullname, globals(), locals(), ['DUMMY'])

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen\_EAB22AC0_30C1_11CF_A7EB_0000C05BAE0B_0_1_1.py", line 401, in <module>
    ( ['out', 'retval'], POINTER(VARIANT_BOOL), 'pfEnabled' )),

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 329, in __setattr__
    self._make_methods(value)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 698, in _make_methods
    prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes)

  File "C:\Users\Namrata\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 123, in WINFUNCTYPE
    class WinFunctionType(_CFuncPtr):
```

The code is

```
import wx.lib.activex
import csv
import comtypes.client

class EventSink(object):

    def __init__(self, frame):
        self.counter = 0
        self.frame = frame

    def DataReady(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.frame.Title= "DataReady fired {0} times".format(self.counter)


class MyApp( wx.App ): 

    def OnClick(self,e):
        rb_selection = self.rb.GetStringSelection()
        if rb_selection == "WinCam":
            data = self.gd.ctrl.GetWinCamDataAsVariant()
            data = [[x] for x in data]
        else:
            p_selection = self.cb.GetStringSelection()
            if p_selection == "Profile_X":
                data = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]#csv.writerows accepts a list of rows where each row is a list, a list of lists
            elif p_selection == "Profile_Y":
                data = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [[x] for x in data]
            else:
                datax = self.px.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                datay = self.py.ctrl.GetProfileDataAsVariant()
                data = [list(row) for row in zip(datax,datay)]#Makes a list of lists; X1 with Y1 in a list, X2 with Y2 in a list etc...
        filename = self.ti.Value
        with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
            w = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            w.writerows(data)

    def __init__( self, redirect=False, filename=None ):
        wx.App.__init__( self, redirect, filename )
        self.frame = wx.Frame( parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY,size=(1000,760), title='Python Interface to DataRay')
        #Panel
        p = wx.Panel(self.frame, wx.ID_ANY)
        #Get Data
        self.gd = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(p, 'DATARAYOCX.GetDataCtrl.1')
        #The methods of the object are available through the ctrl property of the item
        self.gd.ctrl.StartDriver()
        self.counter = 0
        sink = EventSink(self.frame)
        self.sink = comtypes.client.GetEvents(self.gd.ctrl, sink)
        #Button Panel
        bp = wx.Panel(parent=self.frame, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=(215, 250))
        b1 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(200,50), pos=(1, 0),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b1.ctrl.ButtonID =297 #Id's for some ActiveX controls must be set
        b2 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(5, 55),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b2.ctrl.ButtonID =171
        b3 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(110,55),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b3.ctrl.ButtonID =172
        b4 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(5, 85),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b4.ctrl.ButtonID =177
        b4 = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=bp,size=(100,25), pos=(110, 85),axID='DATARAYOCX.ButtonCtrl.1')
        b4.ctrl.ButtonID =179
        #Custom controls
        t = wx.StaticText(bp, label="File:", pos=(5, 115))
        self.ti = wx.TextCtrl(bp, value="C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\output.csv", pos=(30, 115), size=(170, -1))
        self.rb = wx.RadioBox(bp, label="Data:", pos=(5, 140), choices=["Profile", "WinCam"])
        self.cb = wx.ComboBox(bp, pos=(5,200), choices=[ "Profile_X", "Profile_Y", "Both"])
        self.cb.SetSelection(0)
        myb = wx.Button(bp, label="Write", pos=(5,225))
        myb.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick)
        #Pictures
        pic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(250,250),axID='DATARAYOCX.CCDimageCtrl.1')
        tpic = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(250,250), axID='DATARAYOCX.ThreeDviewCtrl.1')
        palette = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(10,250), axID='DATARAYOCX.PaletteBarCtrl.1')
        #Profiles
        self.px = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,200),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.px.ctrl.ProfileID=22
        self.py = wx.lib.activex.ActiveXCtrl(parent=self.frame,size=(300,200),axID='DATARAYOCX.ProfilesCtrl.1')
        self.py.ctrl.ProfileID = 23
        #Formatting 
        row1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row1.Add(window=bp,flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        row1.Add(pic)
        row1.Add(window=tpic, flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)
        row2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        row2.Add(self.px, 0, wx.RIGHT, 100)# Arguments: item, proportion, flags, border
        row2.Add(self.py)
        col1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        col1.Add(sizer=row1, flag=wx.BOTTOM, border=10)
        col1.Add(sizer=row2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
        self.frame.SetSizer(col1)
        self.frame.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = MyApp()
     app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks for the help in advance!